# iPad Media controls

Tags: ios, swift

So i am using the following .swift file to get notification showing the media player controls on the lock screen and notification screen. The following code works fine on iOS but not on iPad.

I have uploaded the full code to Github
https://github.com/redimongo/DRN1

The part in question is what do I need to add for the iPad to get media control?

```
//
//  MusicPlayer.swift
//  DRN1
//
//  Created by Russell Harrower on 25/11/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Russell Harrower. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import Kingfisher

class MusicPlayer {
    static let shared = MusicPlayer()
    var player: AVPlayer?


        func startBackgroundMusic() {

            self.setupRemoteTransportControls()
            let urlString = "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream"
            guard let url = URL.init(string: urlString)
                else {
                    return
            }
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
            player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)



            player?.play()

            do {
              //  try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.duckOthers, .defaultToSpeaker, .mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
                print("Playback OK")
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set("1", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("Session is Active")
            } catch {
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set("0", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
                print(error)
            }

        }




    func setupRemoteTransportControls() {
       // Get the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

        // Add handler for Play Command
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            if self.player?.rate == 0.0 {
                self.player?.play()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }

        // Add handler for Pause Command
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            if self.player?.rate == 1.0 {
                self.player?.pause()
                return .success
            }
            return .commandFailed
        }

       // self.nowplaying(artist: "Anna", song: "test")


    }

    func nowplaying(with artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork, artist: String, song: String){

    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
          MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:song,
          MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:artist,
          MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork,
          MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream: true
    ]


       // self.getArtBoard();
    }


    func setupNowPlayingInfo(with artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork) {
          MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
            //   MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Some name",
            //   MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "Some name",
               MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork,
               //MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.duration),
               //MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: 1,
               //MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime())
           ]
       }



    func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                completion(UIImage(data:data))
            }
        })
            .resume()
    }

    func getArtBoard(artist: String, song: String, cover: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: cover) else { return }
        getData(from: url) { [weak self] image in
            guard let self = self,
                let downloadedImage = image else {
                    return
            }
            let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: downloadedImage.size, requestHandler: { _ -> UIImage in
                return downloadedImage
            })
            self.nowplaying(with: artwork, artist: artist, song: song)
        }
    }



        func stopBackgroundMusic() {
            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.pause()

    }


}
```

I have added with no success

```
override func viewDidLoad() {



        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
               do {
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing the real problem here, running your project on an iPad shows transport controls just fine. They are working as expected even when the app is in the background. Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/cfw1eOM

Comment: @alladinian is that in simulator? Because on iPad 7 simulator it does not work even Apple is saying it does not. I need specs.

Comment: This is from a real device (iPad 6th gen / 2018 / 9.7")

Answer (score 2):

iOS simulators running iOS11+ (including iPadOS) will not show remote control center unless if it’s the default controls created by AVPlayerController. You will need a real device to test `MPRemoteCommandCenter`  or install iOS 10 and lower to run it on simulator.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {          
       super.viewDidLoad()
         // This is an alternative 
        let avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()           
        avPlayerViewController.player = MusicPlayer.shared.player
        avPlayerViewController.player?.play() 

    #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        /*
       if you don’t set up remote controls, the AVPlayer from 
       AVPlayerController will immediately create default remote controls
       otherwise your simulator will not show the controls.
                 */


    #else

     MusicPlayer.shared.setupRemoteTransportControls()
     // more custom controls set up

    #endif

     }
```

Also there is also no need to call `UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()` on devices running iOS 7 and later.

**EDIT : **

```
    —— In your MusicPlayer Class —

   import Foundation
   import AVFoundation
   import MediaPlayer

   import AVKit

class MusicPlayer {
static let shared = MusicPlayer()


var player: AVPlayer?
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()


    func startBackgroundMusic() {


        let urlString = "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream"
        guard let url = URL.init(string: urlString) else { return }

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
        player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)

        do {

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.duckOthers, .defaultToSpeaker, .mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
            print("Playback OK")
           // let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
           // defaults.set("1", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
           // let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
          //  defaults.set("0", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
            print(error)
        }

         #if targetEnvironment(simulator)

         if playerViewController.player == nil {
        playerViewController.player = player
        }
        playerViewController.player?.play()
        print("SIMULATOR")

         #else

        self.setupRemoteTransportControls()
        player?.play()

        #endif

    }




func setupRemoteTransportControls() {
   // Get the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    // Add handler for Play Command
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.player?.rate == 0.0 {
            self.player?.play()
            return .success
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }

    // Add handler for Pause Command
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.player?.rate == 1.0 {
            self.player?.pause()
            return .success
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }

   // self.nowplaying(artist: "Anna", song: "test")


}

func nowplaying(with artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork, artist: String, song: String){

MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
      MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:song,
      MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:artist,
      MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork,
      MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream: true
]


   // self.getArtBoard();
}


func setupNowPlayingInfo(with artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork) {
      MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
        //   MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Some name",
        //   MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "Some name",
           MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork,
           //MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.duration),
           //MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: 1,
           //MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime())
       ]
   }



func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            completion(UIImage(data:data))
        }
    })
        .resume()
}

func getArtBoard(artist: String, song: String, cover: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: cover) else { return }
    getData(from: url) { [weak self] image in
        guard let self = self,
            let downloadedImage = image else {
                return
        }
        let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: downloadedImage.size, requestHandler: { _ -> UIImage in
            return downloadedImage
        })
        self.nowplaying(with: artwork, artist: artist, song: song)
    }
}



     func stopBackgroundMusic() {
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)

     if  playerViewController.player != nil {
        playerViewController.player?.pause()
                   }

      #else

      guard let player = player else { return }
      player.pause()

      #endif

}



}
```

Tested it using iPadOS Simulator (7th Generation)

Comment: I tried your code and in simulator it still did not show the media controls.

Comment: Could I ask you clone my github project and test your code and if you can get it to work upload it please. I am sure your answer is correct.

Comment: You just have to modify your MusicPlayer class. I tested the code, it is working on iPadOS simulator

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then because I am running 
Version 11.2.1 (SimulatorApp-912.4 SimulatorKit-570.3 CoreSimulator-681.15) & Model: iPad (7th generation) iOS 13.2.2 (17B102) 

and it is not showing the controls. Is iPadOS Simulator an app as that seems different to what I am using

Comment: How are you presenting the playerViewController though? The controls will be shown once you present it. Try this :  `let musicPlayer = MusicPlayer.shared
        present(musicPlayer.playerViewController, animated: true)` The only thing that’s not being shown is the art work.

Comment: we don't have a playerViewController. 
The audio is called from FirstViewController. which grabs the now playing info - I recommend downloading the GIT and have a look at the FirstViewController.

NOTE: this is my first ever Swift app so not the neatest code https://github.com/redimongo/DRN1

Its an open project so any hellp given will be shared with others who want to create a radio station app.

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can use the Media Player framework’s [MPRemoteCommandCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandcenter) and [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter) classes with [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer).

You need to invoke beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

**Swift 3+**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents() 
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
```

If you would like to specify custom actions for the `MPRemoteCommandCenter`:

```
let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action:#selector(nextTrackCommandSelector))
```

For more information refer Apple's official [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/controlling_background_audio)

Comment: where do I put these tho - and is this just for iPad?

Comment: do I do it like this func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
         AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }